# no muestra información cuando asocio el XML con XSL

Tags: xml, xsl

No consigo mostrar información con el xsl, me sale en blanco puede que se me escape algún detalle que no veo pero por lo demás esta bien creo yo...

> XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE caja SYSTEM "file:///D:/lenguaje-repaso/pruebaPeque%C3%B1aEscala/dtd.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="file:///D:/lenguaje-repaso/pruebaPeque%C3%B1aEscala/xsl-foreach.xsl"?>
<caja>
  <note id="12234">
    <to>Trove</to>
    <from>Jain</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
  </note>

<comentario id="12234">Ho la Que pass soy UN simplex</comentario> 

<cuadernos>
  <libro fecha="12-14-2010">
    <autor>Hhola</autor>
    <titulo>Ester es Eli titular</titulo>
    <editorial>Es ta es la editorial</editorial>
    <numeroDePaginas>678</numeroDePaginas>
    <precio>4</precio>
  </libro>

  <libro fecha="12-14-2010">
    <autor>hola 2</autor>
    <titulo>Ester es Eli titular 2</titulo>
    <editorial>Es ta es la editorial 2</editorial>
    <numeroDePaginas>628</numeroDePaginas>
    <precio>8</precio>
  </libro>

  <libro fecha="12-14-2010">
    <autor>hola3</autor>
    <titulo>Ester es Eli titular 3</titulo>
    <editorial>Es ta es la editorial 3</editorial>
    <numeroDePaginas>378</numeroDePaginas>
    <precio>6</precio>
  </libro>
</cuadernos>

</caja>
```

> XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>caja</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>autor</th>
      <th>editorial</th>
    </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="caja/Cuadernos/Libro">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="autor"/></td>
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="precio > 7">
                <td bgcolor="#ff00ff"><xsl:value-of select="editorial"/></td>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="editorial"/></td>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> DTD

```
<!ELEMENT caja (note, comentario, cuadernos)>
<!ELEMENT note (to, from, heading, body)>
<!ATTLIST note
   id NMTOKEN #REQUIRED
>
<!ELEMENT to (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT from (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT heading (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT body (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT comentario (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST comentario
   id NMTOKEN #REQUIRED
>
<!ELEMENT cuadernos (libro+)>
<!ELEMENT libro (autor, titulo, editorial, numeroDePaginas, precio)>
<!ATTLIST libro
   fecha NMTOKEN #REQUIRED
>
<!ELEMENT autor (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT titulo (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT editorial (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT numeroDePaginas (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT precio (#PCDATA)>
```

> XSD

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="caja">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>

  <xs:element name="note">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="comentario">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="([a-z])*"/>
      </xs:restriction>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

 <xs:element name="cuadernos">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="libro" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="autor" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="titulo" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="editorial" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="numeroDePaginas" type="xs:integer"/>
              <xs:element name="precio" type="xs:integer"/>
             </xs:sequence>
             <xs:attribute name="fecha" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

> En el XSD me sale un error que no se cual es:
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué navegador utilizas? Creo que Google Chrome no permite utilizar XSLT si utilizas XML directamente. Utiliza F12 para abrir la consola del navegador y comprueba si da alguna información porque XSLT no ha sido aplicado. Si sigues teniendo problemas, muéstranos el DTD también. Como puedes ver en https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2017/test2017081101.xml, tu ejemplo funciona sin DTD y servido por HTTP.

Comment: Yo utilizo "Microsoft Edge".

Comment: Para mi https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2017/test2017081101.xml funciona tanto con Edge como con Chrome. ¿Has tratado de utilizar F12 para abrir la consola de Edge y comprobar si indica algún problema en caso de que tengas una página blanca? En general, por medidas de seguridad, las opciones de utilizar documentas directamente del sistema de archivos de un ordenador por `file:///` URL son más restrictivas que el uso de un servidor y HTTP o HTTPS.

Comment: No @MartinHonnen, no lo he probado.

Answer (score 1):

En el esquema has declarado el prefijo `xs` con `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` y lo has utilizado para la mayoría de los elementos como `xs:schema`, sin embargo, en algunos lugares has utilizado `xsd` en lugar de `xs`, por ejemplo, `xsd:element`. Para corregirlo, tienes que utilizar `xs`, es decir, `xs:element`, en todos los elementos del esquema.

En cuanto a la declaración del elemento "comentario", para declarar un elemento con contenido simple pero con atributo(s) necesitas hacerlo como en el ejemplo https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#complexTfromSimpleT, es decir

```
<xs:simpleType name="letras-ascii-minúsculas">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="([a-z])*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="comentario">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="letras-ascii-minúsculas">                  
                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Es verdad tenia mal el xsd, me sale bien-formado el xml pero el xml no valida (yo asocio el dtd, xsl y xsd juntos, todo) y me sale un error en la viñeta de eventos de abajo del todo de XML copy Editor.

Comment: @Anónimo, parece que la pregunta va desarrollándose, espero que el ejemplo del esquema te ayude aunque no se necesita un esquema para utilizar XSLT.

Comment: vale gracias @Martin Honnen por el comentario, aunque quiero progresar es bueno consejos.

Comment: No puedes asociar un DTD y un XSD como si fuera la misma validación del mismo documento. Si los quieres usar así deben pertenecer a un distinto namespace. Un XSD es una alternativa a un DTD. Te recomiendo que bajes Altova XMLspy que es un software para validar XML. Ahora una plantilla de transformación lleva extensión XSLT no XSL. XSL es el nombre de la tecnología. Si quieres hacer una transformación así te recomiendo que bajes Altova StyleVisión que es un software que ayuda a crear transformaciones XSL.